# Specifying content type of http multipart request with mime

Tags: flutter, dart, mime-types

I have found mime package https://pub.dev/packages/mime just recently for determining mime type of file. I'm trying to now use it in http multipart request, content type. This is how I managed to do it so far

```
  Future<void> createProfile(Profile profile) async {
    try {
      var request =
          new http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(APIPath.createProfile()));
      request.fields.addAll(profile.toMap());
      if (profile.image != null) {
        final mime = lookupMimeType(profile.image.path).toString(); //<- get mime type
        request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
            'image', profile.image.path,
            contentType:
                MediaType(mime.split('/').first, mime.split('/').last))); //<- split mime
      }
      request.headers['authorization'] = "Bearer $_token";
      final response = await request.send();
      if (response.statusCode != 201) {
        print('Done')
      }

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to set content type with mime package without splitting it in MediaType?

Comment: Pay attention: you need declare a boundary with the Content Type https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Comment: That's the reason why in most multipart request the content type is automatically set

Comment: @GreilOmatics I believe that is automatically set by http package. I mean I didn't see that to be set in documentation of http package. I will have to look at it but thanks for pointing that out